# Proving $f$ is Riemann integrable on a restricted domain by contradiction

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory

This is a problem from Sheldon Axler's Measure, Integration and Real Analysis.

[image]

I am trying to prove this by contradiction, but there are two steps doubting me.

Assume that for all partitions $P$ of $[c,d]$ , $\exists \epsilon $ s.t

$U(f,P,[c,d]) - L(f,P,[c,d]) \geq \epsilon$

But since $f$ is integrable on $[a,b]$ , then $\exists P'$ s.t

$U(f,P',[a,b]) - L(f,P',[a,b]) < \epsilon$

Now I want to intersect $P'$ with $[c,d]$ and call the partition $P''$, but here comes my question, how am I sure that $P'$ contains the endpoints of $[c,d]$?

My second question is, assuming that $P'$ does contain the endpoints $c$ & $d$, I want to use the following theorem:

[image]

But as far as I understand, to use this theorem with $P''$ and $P'$, they both have to be partitions of the same interval? But $P''$ is supposedly a partition of $[c,d]$ while $P'$ is a partition of $[a,b]$ so I am clueless on how to setup those inequalities if I got that issue.

Thank you.

Comment: You should be able to note that an upper sum on a partion $P$ of $[a, b] $ is the sum of upper sums on restriction of $P$ to $[a, c], [c, d], [d, b] $. This assumes that $P$ contains the points $c, d$. But this is not a major issue as one can always refine $P$ by adding $c, d$ to it.

Comment: I noted that and I tried to use it, if I call the restricted partitions $P_1 , P_2 , P_3$ then I know that $U(f,P_{1},[a,c]) + U(f,P_{2},[c,d]) + U(f,P_{3},[d,b]) - L(f,P_{1},[a,c]) - L(f,P_{2},[c,d]) - L(f,P_{3},[d,b]) < \epsilon$

Not sure how to extract $ U(f,P_{2},[c,d]) -  L(f,P_{2},[c,d]) < \epsilon $ from this.

Comment: Do you know that $U-L\geq 0$? And hence the expression can be written as a sum of three non negative values of $U-L$ and one of these corresponds to $[c, d] $. If sum of three non-negative numbers is less than $\epsilon $ then each of them must also be less than $\epsilon $.

Comment: Often the arguments in analysis are really very easy, but the symbolism makes it difficult to figure out.

Comment: I appreciate the fact that you have given all the relevant context (including your effort). +1

Comment: Oh, it was all within my reach and I decided to overcomplicate it, thank you! Definitely something to look out for in future problems.

Answer (score 3):

Hint:  Once you have your partition $P'$,  you can take a refinement of $P'$ as $P'\cup \{c,d\}$.   That will guarantee you can split apart the partition of $[a,b]$ into the three parts,  $[a,c],[c,d],[d,b]$.   A refinement only improves the estimate.   Can you finish?

Edited to add:  With this, you don't even need contradiction.

Comment: Thank you, I finished with your help and help from the comments.